# How to get video status with id

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I've been looking through the youtube API v3 all day and can't figure how to know if a video is still available querying the api with the video ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the next endpoint:  https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status&id=saEjTy1pJHA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if the video isn't available or if was removed, I just have no answer from the api. I mean that it just tell me there is no result. for exemple : https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status&id=B51S619xtDg&key=

Comment: This is the answer I get from youtube for the video ID you put in your comment http://puu.sh/9KTk8/13f816582e.png Basically, I would think that if items has not any item is because it has been removed or it is not available.

Comment: Okay, so if I query 50 id, and get only 4 answers, I will need to compare the id's of the ones who are returned with the 50 who were queried to see wich one isn't available? I thought there was an easier way. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I am afraid you would need to check it in that way, unless until I know.